# How to amend LDAP connection properties in LDAPCertStore for X509 cert chain validation

Tags: java, oracle, security, validation, pki

I'm trying to validate X509 certificate chain using sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator according to [Oracle official guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html). One of the steps in validation is to check CRLs. I'm providing LDAPCertStore to get the CRL from LDAP. But LDAPCertStore cannot handle server closing connection becuase `java.security.cert.LDAPCertStoreParameters` lacks settings for LDAPConnection.

Is it possible to amend LDAP connection properties e.g. using [LDAP Connection Pooling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html) (system properties doesn't help, bouncy castle has the same implementation regarding connections)?
Please see code to reproduce below:

```
@Test
public void testRevocationListValidation() throws Exception {
    String trustStoreFile = "trustStoreFilePath";
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(trustStoreFile);
    if (is == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.format("KeyStore file '%s' is not found on classpath", trustStoreFile));
    }
    trustStore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
    Set<TrustAnchor> trustedAnchors = new HashSet<TrustAnchor>();
    for (String caCertificateAlias : new String[]{"ca"}) {
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) trustStore.getCertificate(caCertificateAlias);
        trustedAnchors.add(new TrustAnchor(certificate, null));
    }
    PKIXParameters parameters = new PKIXParameters(trustedAnchors);
    CertStore certStore = CertStore.getInstance("LDAP", new LDAPCertStoreParameters("ldapHost", 389));
    parameters.setCertStores(Collections.singletonList(certStore));

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("keystore.jks"), "password".toCharArray());

    String keyStoreAlias = "dev-test";
    Certificate[] userCertificateChain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(keyStoreAlias);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Starting validation " + i);
        CertPath userCertificatePath = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertPath(Arrays.asList(userCertificateChain));
        CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX").validate(userCertificatePath, parameters);
        System.out.println("Validation " + i + " succeeded");
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println("Sleeping after second validation");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(90); // Server connection timeout ~ 60 sec
        }
    }

}
```

Sample output:

> Starting validation 0
>
> Validation 0 succeeded
>
> Starting validation 1
>
> Validation 1 succeeded
>
> Sleeping after second validation
>
> Starting validation 2
>
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
> java.security.cert.CertStoreException:
> javax.naming.CommunicationException: connection closed [Root exception
> is java.io.IOException: **connection closed**]; remaining name

Comment: Looks like root is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787577/how-to-reconnect-when-the-ldap-server-is-restarted

Comment: I've created ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Java 9 - LDAP connection would be restored automatically
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059009